# How to serialize into a raw memory block?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

It is really easy to serialize a c++ object to file with boost,

```
std::ofstream ofile( lpszFileName );
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofile);
oa << m_rgPoints;
```

But how could I serialize a c++ object into a raw memory block?

Should I read the output file stream into memory or is there any other better method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write own `streambuf` class, what works directly on your memory:

```
class membuf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
  membuf( char * mem, size_t size )
  {
    this->setp( mem, mem + size );
    this->setg( mem, 0, mem + size );
  }
  int_type overflow( int_type charval = traits_type::eof() )
  {
    return traits_type::eof();
  }
  int_type underflow( void )
  {
    return traits_type::eof();
  }
  int sync( void )
  {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Use this class:

```
  membuf buf(address,size);
  ostream os(&buf);
  istream is(&buf);

  oss << "Write to the buffer";
```

Comment: This would be even shinier if you didn't have to specify the buffer size in advance. But perhaps the question implies this as a requirement.

Answer (score 7):

**Edited in response to comments from James Kanze:**

You could serialize into a `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
oa << m_rgPoints;
```

And then read from that by getting the `std::streambuf` (calling `oss.rdbuf()`) and calling `streambuf::sgetn` on that to read the data into your own buffer.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/rdbuf/

This avoids an unnecessary temporary file.

Comment: Just for the record: the `ios_base::binary` flag is ignored by `stringbuf`; it's only really relevant for `filebuf` (`ifstream`, `ofstream`).  And since you're just writing, wouldn't `ostringstream` be more appropriate.

Comment: I didn't realise that binary was only relevant for filebuf. Thanks for that, and of course ostringstream would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a serialization wrapper for binary raw data, [`binary_object`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html).

You can use it like:

```
// buf is a pointer to a raw block of memory, size its size
// oa is a boost archive
boost::serialization::binary_object buf_wrap(buf, size);
oa << buf_wrap
```

Another option, with c++17 is to convert the buffer to a `std::vector` of `std::byte`. As detailed in the [reference of `reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), it is allowed to cast the pointer to a `byte *` and the dereference it. So, one could use a code like:

```
// buf is a pointer to a raw block of memory, size its size
// oa is a boost archive
auto start_buf = reinterpret_cast<byte *>(buf);
std::vector<std::byte> vec(start_buf, start_buf + size);
oa << vec;
```

This implies however a copy.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you need binary serialization `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`. Then you can copy data from stream.